# If quadrilateral ABCD = quadrilateral PQRS, then {A,B,C,D}={P,Q,R,S}

Tags: geometry

Prove that if $\square ABCD = \square PQRS$, then $\{A,B,C,D\}=\{P,Q,R,S\}$. The definition I am given of $\square$ABCD = $\overline{AB}$ $\cup$ $\overline{BC}$ $\cup$ $\overline{CD}$ $\cup$  $\overline{DA}$. Where these segments only intersect at vertices. I tried a proof by contradiction but there are too many cases that arise for the proof to flow. It gets confusing. There has to be a better way to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The segments only intersect at vertices, so no three points are collinear.  This means that any P, Q, R, or S won't lie on any of the intervals' interiors, hence they must lie on the vertices.  Therefore {A,B,C,D}={P,Q,R,S} so long as the sets need not be ordered...except they do.  Otherwise one might be a bowtie while the other a quadrilateral.  But this would violate the assumption that ABCD = PQRS, so we have some outline of a proof?

Did that help?

Comment: Actually, this proof doesn't require that {A,B,C,D}={P,Q,R,S} be in that order. There is a follow up question that shows order. This is a good start!